# Lint Warning: #647: Suspicious truncation

Tags: c, lint, truncation, pc-lint, armcc

I have read the related questions to this Lint warning about the suspicious truncation, but here it is a purely C case.

The following line is where the `Warning #647` pops up:

```
pCont->sig -= (signed int64_t)((sub2 << 8)/pCont->freq + 1);
```

where `pCont->sig` is also 64 bit signed (type `signed int64_t`), and both `sub2` and `freq` are 32 bit unsigned. All this is compiled with armcc.

Already tried, without success, to cast the `1` to unsigned 32 bit, but the problem persists.

Any idea on what I might try, or what is going wrong here?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `int64_t` is already defined to be `signed`, you don't need to specify `signed` again when using it. See e.g. [this fixed-width integer reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).

Comment: Do you need: `((int64_t)sub2 << 8) / pCont->freq + 1`?

Comment: The basic questions you have to answer for yourself: "why are you using a signed type to store the value when it can never be negative?"  And "why are you storing it as a 63-bit value when the expression can never produce more than 32 valid bits?"  And it won't hurt to think about "What happens when sub2 is too large and the value overflows?"  Only after you can say "I meant to do that!" can you suppress the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this reference about the warning](http://www.gimpel.com/html/bugs/bug647.htm)

> For example:
>
> ```
> (long) (n << 8)
> ```
>
> might elicit this message if n is unsigned int, whereas
>
> ```
> (long) n << 8
> ```
>
> would not.  In the first case, the shift is done at int precision
>   and the high order 8 bits are lost even though there is a
>   subsequent conversion to a type that might hold all the bits.  In
>   the second case, the shifted bits are retained.

This seems to fit your case *exactly* and also show you how to fix it.

Comment: `lint` warning is gone! Your explanation is clear an on point. I'm happy; my boss is happy; my QA colleague is happy :-)